# Origin Points (and Colliders) Not Moving with Armature

Tags: armature, rigid-body-simulation, collision, origin

I don't know if this has already been addressed elsewhere, but I couldn't seem to find any information on this issue.

I'm trying to make a chain of rigid bodies using bones and empty axis(s) with colliders and constraints (to be able to simulate hair, ropes, etc.)

Only I've come across an interesting situation that has prevented me from moving forward. Here I have the cube shape parented to the bone at rest position.
[image]

When the bone is rotates, the mesh moves with it, but the collider gets left behind and warps. When I select the mesh, it shows me that the origin has not moved. I think this is perhaps the problem, the origin is not moving with the bone. 
[image]

I have tried parenting the mesh to the bone as 'bone' or 'with automatic weights' or simply by painting, but none of these have changed the result. Also adjusting where rotation happens doesn't seem to have an effect either.

Not sure if there's anything that can be done, or if I should try a different method?